# Weird text after Unzipping

Tags: character-encoding, zip, unzip

After unzipping a file and reading some .txt files in it i noticed that the text files were messed up.

There were lots of equal signs like this ==~ scatter amongst words , and in some words letters were jumbled and unreadable.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Also some files were left empty after unzipping.

To unzip i used the command like unzip tool with no parameters.

It showed errors such as `bad CRC b2fd8b3e  (should be ac92cdc0)` 
and

```
file #21:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  249997
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the Zip files are corrupt, or the tool you're using doesn't correctly handle the compression algorithm used.